# Mootools - how to fix variable scope inside initialize and inside a ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, request, scope

I cant get my for loop to read the maxSlots variable outside of the request. I dont know how or where to declare the variable to make it local to each class but global for the hole class.

```
//INITIALIZATION
initialize: function(){

    maxSlots = 0;
    var myRequest = new Request({

            url: 'getInventory.php',
            method: 'post',     
            onSuccess: function(responseText){

                maxSlots = responseText;
                console.log(maxSlots);
            },

            onSFailure: function(){
                alert('noo');
            }       

    });
    myRequest.send();

    for (var i = 1; i <= maxSlots; i++){

        var slot = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        slot.inject(invContainer);
    }


}
```

EDIT:
Ok I tried changing the variable into an option, the alert inside the request = 12 but if i make an alert after the request it says undefined... still the same problem.

```
//VARIABLES
options: {
    id: '',
    size: '',
    maxSlots: '2'
},

//INITIALIZATION
initialize: function(options){

    this.setOptions(options);
    var myRequest = new Request({

            url: 'getInventory.php',
            method: 'post',     
            onSuccess: function(responseText){

                this.maxSlots = responseText;
                alert(this.maxSlots)
            },

            onSFailure: function(){
                alert('noo');
            }       

    });
    myRequest.send();

            alert(this.maxSlots)
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.maxSlots; i++){

        var slot = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        slot.inject(invContainer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
   initialize: function(){

        this.maxSlots = 0;
        var myRequest = new Request({

            url: 'getInventory.php',
            method: 'post',     
            onSuccess: function(responseText){

                this.maxSlots = responseText;
                console.log(this.maxSlots);
            }.bind(this),  // <-- always bind the scope in functions

            onSFailure: function(){
                alert('noo');
            }       

    });
    myRequest.send();

    for (var i = 1; i <= this.maxSlots; i++){

        var slot = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        slot.inject(invContainer);
    }


}
```

you could also save the variable in the `this.options`

Good Luck

Comment: great thanx for your fast reply that bind worked like a charm needed to use this.options.maxSlots tho whithout it nothing happend :D but i dont really understand why it works, what does that bind do?

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:bind You need to bind the scope because the scope of the success function is not the same as scope of the class. When you use bind, you're sayin "inside the function, use the Class' `this` instead of the function's `this`" =P it's hard for me to explain it

Comment: er. let us know if this works for you, ajax is async which means the loop over `this.maxSlots` won't work as expected, the data will arrive later with the event and at runtime, the loop wont do much as `this.maxSlots` will be 0.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff is rigth.. you need to add `async:false` to your Request object or put the loop inside the onSuccess() method

Comment: working with events/promises and callbacks from the success is the better way to go. sync ajax = defeatist, imo - and breaks the web, kills kittens etc :)

Comment: yeah thanks I found that problem and put the loop in the onSuccess method and deleated the first variable declaration of this.maxSlots = 0; and it works great now :D